# php form to Oracle - How do i handle FORM Data before insert

Tags: php, html, oracle, forms, oracle11g

When I INSERT or UPDATE an Oracle Database from a PHP form - I am capturing the FORM data and sanitizing it through a function that trims, stripslashes and htmlspecialcharacters the data.

I want to keep ampersands, single quotes and double quotes in the DB as is...

But recently I am wondering about this function. I thought it was to help with sql injection, but OCI8 avoids this through binding variables - which I do...

How do I handle single quotes?

Wont allowing single quotes terminate the string?

I am thinking I might need to rewrite this function a bit - Do I even need it?

can anyone help with this function check_input($data) and give me feedback?

```
<?php
require('conn.php');
require('db.php');
$conn = db_connect();

  $form1 = check_input($_POST['issueType']);
  $form2 = check_input($_POST['summary']);
  $form3 = check_input($_POST['endPointName']);
  $form4 = check_input($_POST['contactFirstName']);
  $form5 = check_input($_POST['contactLastName']);
  $form6 = check_input($_POST['contactEmail']);
  $form7 = check_input($_POST['contactPhone']);
  $form8 = check_input($_POST['description']);


  // trims data, strips extra characters, converts special characters to HTML entities

  function check_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
   }

  $insert = "INSERT INTO VTC_HELPDESK_ISSUES (ISSUE_TYPE, ISSUE_SHORT,ENDPOINT_NAME,CONTACT_FIRST_NAME,CONTACT_LAST_NAME, CONTACT_EMAIL,CONTACT_PHONE,ISSUE_DESC,SOLUTION,OTHER_COMPANY_TICKET_NUM,RESOLVED,AGENCY) VALUES (:issueType, :summary,:endPointName, :contactFirstName, :contactLastName,:contactEmail, :contactPhone, :description, :solution, :ticketNumber, :resolved, :agency)";

  $send = oci_parse($conn, $insert);

  //Binding makes it harder to submit anything directly to the Oracle DB
  oci_bind_by_name($send, ':issueType', $form1);
  oci_bind_by_name($send, ':summary', $form2);
  oci_bind_by_name($send, ':endPointName', $form3);
  oci_bind_by_name($send, ':contactFirstName', $form4);
  oci_bind_by_name($send, ':contactLastName', $form5);
  oci_bind_by_name($send, ':contactEmail', $form6);
  oci_bind_by_name($send, ':contactPhone', $form7);
  oci_bind_by_name($send, ':description', $form8);


  oci_execute($send);
```

?>

Comment: By binding the variables in the query you are doing all that is necessary to protect your database from injection. What is your goal for the `check_input()` function?

Comment: The standard practice is to put data in the DB precisely as it is given to you and escape on output since you will never be 100% sure where the output will be displayed. A web page is going to have different sanitation rules compared to a Visual Basic form or an API output.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - my goal is just to be secure and not have alot of funky characters in the db, and yet display them so its readable and updateable on a web page..

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - So if I allow single quotes in, they are in the DB, show on the webpage, but when I fetch from the DB and prepopulate on the update page - the field gets terminated at the quote - ???

Comment: When displaying the data for a web page then use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and use it like this `echo htmlentites($row['DB_COLUMN'], ENT_QUOTES);` and that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Because "Binding is important for Oracle database performance and also as a way to avoid SQL Injection security issues"*, you can stop doing your own check_input() on those fields.  In specific, you are losing your quotes and ampersands to the htmlspecialchars().

[* php.net/oci_bind_by_name](http://php.net/oci_bind_by_name)